# How to know what project is being run in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

I have visual studio solution with multiple projects. In one of the file which will also be used by multiple projects, some part of the code, I only want to run by specific project only. I'm thinking to use #if directive for visual studio. The problem is, where can I get the information telling what project currently being run so that I can do checking in the statement below?

```
#If <statement>

codes that should only run by specific project only...

#End If
```

Answer (score 0):

In VB project properties **Compile** - **Advanced Compile Options** you can add a custom constant (e.g. SpecialProject):

[image]

And then check it in code like this:

```
#If SpecialProject Then

        Console.WriteLine("special")

#End If
```